# How do you create a swimlane in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I need to create a swimlane style for my process map, how do I do this?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39132/in-draw-io-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-position-a-swimlane-or-process-diagr

Answer (score 13):

You can add swimlanes to the existing default 3 by right-clicking the last swimlane's title and selecting "Duplicate". Then move the inserted swimlane up/down by right-clicking its title and selecting "To Back" or "To Front" respectively.

Comment: but if I want to move up/down by 1 step, not to top-most/bottom-most?

Answer (score 4):

The swimlane is the first element in the `general` shapes library, named `container`.

To rotate, you currently select *Arrange* → *Direction* → *Rotation*  from the menu and enter *270* (degrees) for a horizontal swimlane.

Rotation handles are in testing, which will make rotation easier, you can see them using the [rotation=1 URL parameter](https://www.draw.io/?rotation=1).

Answer (score 4):

The swimlanes now (06/28/14) seem to be at the bottom of the "Advanced" category and are called Pools. There are two types of vertical pools and two types of horizontal pools.

Answer (score 3):

You can create new swimlanes by copying an existing one, paste and drag it into the Pool section. Draw.io will automatically pop it under the last swimlane for you.

Comment: never realize drag and drop into pool will solve my problem, :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1):

To create a swim lane just type swimlane on the search menu. To add more swim lanes, click on the arrow button in the swim lanes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting a swim lane diagram**

1. Open the `Shapes` dialog
2. Go to the `BPMN 2.0 General` section
3. Select `Horizontal Pool 1`
   [image]

**Adding an additional swim lane**

1. Select the swim lane container
2. Go to `Format` → `Arrange` → `Table`
3. Select for example `Insert Row After`

[image]